# Can Xfinity remotely reset a private, non-owned modem?

Tags: modem, remote

My Netgear C7100V reset itself at the same time Xfinity was doing some system maintenance. When I tried to login it just asked me to set a new password.

Netgear technical support said that Xfinity must have reset it, and that Xfinity could reset it the Netgear modem remotely.

I purchased this modem. It's not Xfinity equipment. But it is advertised as Xfinity approved and compatible.

Can they do that to a modem they don't own? Are there standard protocols in place that give them access?

Comment: Xfinity I am sure has a way to check to see if your modem even if it's not their actual product is operating as expected like all other ISPs. The ISPs have the ability to reset the modem if they need to.

Comment: @moab is wrong. Yes they can. They may not own it, but it is certified to work on their network because it operates under their auspices. I purchased a modem rather than renting from them, and xfinity has full control of it.